# pyqgis - refreshing only QgsMapCanvasItems not the entire QgsMapCanvas

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a fairly complex map, consisting of many layers, and despite they're optimized, they still take a certain time to refresh. I also have a QgsMapCanvasItem representing my position, which i would like to have updated about 20 times per second. This could be easily done, if it was possible to only update the position of the QgsMapCanvasItem, and use a cached image of what is displayed in the map canvas. Is this possible?

Comment: 20 times per second? That's probably more than what a user is able to perceive. On the other hand, have you tried just removing your latest position and adding your new position to the map? I worked with QgsVertexMarker few years ago, and never refreshed the map by myself, just added and removed markers.

Comment: I actually think it is quite possible, that map canvas image is cached anyway, and isnt actually rerendered unless extents/scale of the canvas change. This means that by ignoring position updates when user pans or scrolls the map, it could be done... i ll investigate some more

Comment: In the end, i solved it by modifying the refresh rate based on the scale. A kind of a compromising solution

Comment: In that case, please consider posting your solution as an answer.

Comment: Well, it isn't really a solution. What i did was respond to scaleChanged event, setting a different refresh ratio each time. For example: 10 seconds if scale > 100000, 5 seconds if its < 50000,... One thing to point out also, is you should definitely use QgsMapCanvasItem(s) instead of vector layers, because if you dont, changing data in the layers causes refresh of the entire map canvas, and the map flickers.